# Int is not convertible to T

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have the following protocol

```
public protocol NumericType {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func addWithOverflow(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Self) -> (Self, overflow: Bool)
}
```

Also I am extending Int to conforms to it as follows

```
extension Int : NumericType { }
```

Then I have a struct with the following definition

```
struct State<T:NumericType>  {

    let current : T

    init(current : T) {

        self.current = current
    }

    static func initial() -> State<T> {

        return State(current: 0) // Int is not convertible to T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumericType` does not promise that it is `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, so there's no way to convert `0` (which is assumed to be an `Int` here) to `T`. Your protocol needs to provide some `.zero` that it knows it can initialize with (or it needs to conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`).